# Как добавить серый слой на гугл карту

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps-api

Как можно добавить поверх карты серый цвет, ну или карту как сделать черно-белой. И хотелось бы, чтоб на карту можно было кликать при этом :)

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      var map;
      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
          zoom: 8
        });
      }
    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBNPpmrNOp_dyxwKRa7VFekvHt4ARNyWMk&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте [Google Map Styling Wizard](https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/). С его помощью создайте json, вставьте его в свой скрипт как переменную. Создайте стиль с помощью StyledMapType и прикрепите его к карте с помощью map.mapTypes.set и map.setMapTypeId.

См. сниппет:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Simple Map</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>
    /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
    
    #map {
      height: 100%;
    }
    /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
    
    html,
    body {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map"></div>
  <script>
    // KAGG style
    var KAGG = [{
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [{
          "color": "#244059"
        }]
      },
      {
        "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
        "stylers": [{
          "color": "#8ec3b9"
        }]
      },
      {
        "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
        "stylers": [{
          "color": "#1a3646"
        }]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "administrative",
        "stylers": [{
          "visibility": "off"
        }]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "administrative.country",
        "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
        "stylers": [{
            "color": "#4b6878"
          },
          {
            "visibility": "on"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "administrative.land_parcel",
        "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
        "stylers": [{
          "color": "#64779e"
        }]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "administrative.locality",
        "stylers": [{
          "visibility": "off"
        }]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "administrative.province",
        "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
        "stylers": [{
            "color": "#4b6878"
          },
          {
            "visibility": "off"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "landscape",
        "elementType": "labels",
        "stylers": [{
          "visibility": "off"
        }]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "landscape.man_made",
        "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
        "stylers": [{
            "color": "#334e87"
          },
          {
            "visibility": "off"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "landscape.natural",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [{
          "color": "#023e58"
        }]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "poi",
        "stylers": [{
          "visibility": "off"
        }]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "poi",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [{
            "color": "#283d6a"
          },
          {
            "visibility": "off"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "poi",
        "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
        "stylers": [{
            "color": "#6f9ba5"
          },
          {
            "visibility": "off"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "poi",
        "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
        "stylers": [{
            "color": "#1d2c4d"
          },
          {
            "visibility": "off"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "poi.park",
        "elementType": "geometry.fill",
        "stylers": [{
            "color": "#023e58"
          },
          {
            "visibility": "off"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "poi.park",
        "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
        "stylers": [{
            "color": "#3c7680"
          },
          {
            "visibility": "off"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "road",
        "stylers": [{
          "visibility": "off"
        }]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "road",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [{
            "color": "#304a7d"
          },
          {
            "visibility": "off"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "road",
        "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
        "stylers": [{
            "color": "#98a5be"
          },
          {
            "visibility": "off"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "road",
        "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
        "stylers": [{
            "color": "#1d2c4d"
          },
          {
            "visibility": "off"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "road.highway",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [{
          "color": "#2c6675"
        }]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "road.highway",
        "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
        "stylers": [{
          "color": "#255763"
        }]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "road.highway",
        "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
        "stylers": [{
          "color": "#b0d5ce"
        }]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "road.highway",
        "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
        "stylers": [{
          "color": "#023e58"
        }]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "transit",
        "stylers": [{
          "visibility": "off"
        }]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "transit",
        "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
        "stylers": [{
            "color": "#98a5be"
          },
          {
            "visibility": "off"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "transit",
        "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
        "stylers": [{
            "color": "#1d2c4d"
          },
          {
            "visibility": "off"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "transit.line",
        "elementType": "geometry.fill",
        "stylers": [{
            "color": "#283d6a"
          },
          {
            "visibility": "off"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "transit.station",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [{
            "color": "#3a4762"
          },
          {
            "visibility": "off"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "water",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [{
          "color": "#0e1626"
        }]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "water",
        "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
        "stylers": [{
            "color": "#4e6d70"
          },
          {
            "visibility": "off"
          }
        ]
      }
    ];
    var map;

    function initMap() {
      // Declare new style
      var KAGGstyledMap = new google.maps.StyledMapType(KAGG, {
        name: "KAGG"
      });

      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {
          lat: -34.397,
          lng: 150.644
        },
        zoom: 8
      });

      // Setup skin for the map
      map.mapTypes.set('KAGG_style', KAGGstyledMap);
      map.setMapTypeId('KAGG_style');

    }
  </script>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBNPpmrNOp_dyxwKRa7VFekvHt4ARNyWMk&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
</body>

</html>
```